# Campaign not showing up in Adobe Test & Target

Tags: aem, test-and-target

Created a new Campaign, and this is not showing up in Adobe Target. Not sure what i am missing. Appreciate any help or advice.

Steps i've done:

1. The configuration on AEM Cloud services to connect to Target is already setup and shows the message "Adobe Test & Target configuration is successful..." There is a "configuration" and "framework" setup.
2. I ACTIVATED this service
3. In WCM, under Campaigns, created a new Campaign.. and in the Properties > Cloud services selected the above Test&Target config
4. ACTIVATED the Campaign

I am assuming that at this point, the Campaign should show up in Adobe Target but is not showing.

Comment: Here's some comments in the Adobe Forums (but did not solve my problem yet..)  [http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__hfxi-created_a_newcampai.html#forum__hfxi-created_a_newcampai__sta2-thanks_sekharwet]

Answer (score 0):

Add a offer Page to the campaign.
Activate the offer page.
Check in the experience from aem if you are able to resolve the segmentation from target to your targeted content.